# Entity Framework order by string in over 10 million rows

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework, linq

I need to order and filter through over 10 million rows of document names (so I can't modify the string). I currently have around 2 mils of rows and it returns the result in over 10-15 seconds after an order by or where clause. 
I would prefer an EF solution, not a database one, but I am open to any solution.
Here is some code, although i don't consider it useful:

```
var orderedQuery = dbItems.OrderBy(a => a.DocumentName);
dbItems = dbItems.Where(a=>
          a.DocumentName.ToLower().Contains(filter.DocumentName.ToLower()));
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Entity Framework, but are you as it appears above first ordering the data by DocumentName and then filtering down to the DocumentNames that match your criteria?  If so you are doing it backwards: filter the data down to a smaller set, and then order that smaller set.

Comment: I can order without filtering. First load is without a filter. I am using this for an infinite scroll.

Comment: So your first load returns all 10 million rows, ordered by DocumentName?  That doesn't seem advisable - no one will scroll through that, so they'll only ever see the documents with names like "Aardvark 1".  Why not withhold the data until you know what they are looking for?

Comment: Well, I was not the one to write the business logic. I just have to do it. I know it's stupid, but I asked how can it be done, not if it should be done.

Comment: You would be surprised how bored can someone be to want to scroll through 10 million documents :))

Comment: OK, well unless those documents happen to be stored in the database already ordered by DocumentName, then to return all 10 million ordered by DocumentName is going to require some heavy lifting under the covers .  What you can do (in SQL anyway) is use a hint to inform Oracle that there is a user browsing this and they'd like the first few rows back fast - `select /*+ first_rows(15) */ * from documents order by document_name;`  Then Oracle may choose an execution plan that gets the first rows back quickly but would take longer to get back all the rows - e.g. index lookups rather than hash join

Comment: See http://blog.devart.com/using-oracle-optimizer-hints-in-entity-framework.html

Comment: Did you try profiling your query? It might help you to see the issue with query generation and possible missing indexes.

Comment: @TonyAndrews I already have a PagingHelper using the query to return first n rows which needs the entire list of items for it to work. Adding that extra hint seems one more thing to further extend the execution time. And I cannot un-use it...

Comment: Are you saying that this "PagingHelper" thing requires you to fetch **all** the rows that the query returns into some sort of local storage so that it can then start paging it?  That you intend to fetch 10 million sorted rows from the database into this "PagingHelper" for it to then present to the user.  Please say I'm mistaken, because that is a ludicrous idea and cannot be expected to perform well.  Stop and think!

Answer (score 0):

You should work with the initial orderedQuery in your second query rather than querying dbItems again. I would also advise adding AsNoTracking to your first linq query as this will no doubt increase performance significantly

```
var orderedQuery = dbItems.AsNotracking().OrderBy(a => a.DocumentName);

var filteredList = orderedQuery.Where(a=>
      a.DocumentName.ToLower().Contains(filter.DocumentName.ToLower()));
```

Try this and let us know how it goes.